# Dynamics GP Web Service Call Issue

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to GetVendorList and having issue reconstructing the context object.

Get following error.

```
The specified type was not recognized: name='CompanyKey', namespace='http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/
```

Here is the Soap Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/gp/2006/01" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/security/2006/01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:GetVendorList>
<ns:criteria>
<ns:Id>
<ns:NotEqualValue>-1</ns:NotEqualValue>
</ns:Id>
</ns:criteria>
<ns:context>
    <ns1:OrganizationKey xsi:type="ns2:CompanyKey">
        <ns2:Id>1</ns2:Id>
    </ns1:OrganizationKey>
</ns:context>
</ns:GetVendorList>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

We have a number of databases hooked up the service, so we want to be able to select that in the method call.

I would like to know what the CompanyKey() object should look like.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508733.aspx

Comment: Are you able to solve this? Stuck with passing the context as well.

Comment: I was able to make it work, if need details let me know and will share the information.. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Company id, is actually a CompanyKey as explained by information in the link.
Use below query to see the information from table.

select CMPANYID,INTERID,CMPNYNAM,* from SY01500.

Comment: It's stupid to down vote, because picture has been added in a reply, without thinking that picture is showing query and the fields of table where company information get saved. It's seems that as if someone is down voting because s/he has a privilege to down vote. childish .